# Добавить папки, доступ которым можно получить без путя Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, импорт, path, create-react-app

По дефолту только к папке node_modules можно подкл без указания пути, только по названию, для доступа к библиотекам. У меня есть папки доступ к которым нужно получить из жопы проекта, в итоге выходит путь типа

```
import { name } from '../../../../../../';
```

это прям сильно некрасиво выглядит и я знаю что можно добавлять свои папки. Подскажите путь и название файла где и как это можно сделать.

Видел на ютубе, но там версия CRA старая, всё совсем по-другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается в конфиге [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/):

```
const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      //...
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
          Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/')
        }
      }
    };
```